# Parsing custom document to JSON in incorrect format via PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am currently parsing a large document with the following format

DOCUMENT PREVIEW: https://ghostbin.com/paste/mwckv

which I parse ***fine*** as far as I can see, I convert this to JSON so my application can parse it when it needs it. However I just noticed the JSON is in the wrong format for my needs.

MY *PHP* CODE: https://ghostbin.com/paste/pbg4n (UPDATED)

I need my JSON so it has KEY => VALUE, it is currently "KEY: VALUE", I have tried multiple answers on here however from my searching no one else really has this problem!

CURRENT JSON: https://ghostbin.com/paste/4rdqo

NEED TO BE JSON: https://ghostbin.com/paste/rkbn4

I really need some help with this.

P.S. Sorry about the links I have more code than I do need to put in this post!

Comment: Show your php code.

Comment: I have, it's in the "MY CODE" Link.

Comment: You don't need to keep calling `str_replace()`.  Just call it once and supply it with an array of `finds` and `replaces`.  Are you saying you need to `FORCE` the subarrays to be `OBJECT`s?  I'll see if I can completely clean your process up.

Comment: Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly better way to do it, do the replacements but instead of straight replacing for nothing or the key, prepare it for `parse_str()`, which will parse out into an array.

So like this:

```
<?php
$txt = 'BEGIN:VEVENT
//snipp...
END:VEVENT';

function prep_vcard($str) {
    return str_replace([
        '\n',
        'BEGIN:VEVENT',
        'END:VEVENT',
        'DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:',
        'DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:',
        'DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:',
        'UID:',
        'DESCRIPTION:',
        'Teacher:',
        'Period:',
        'SUMMARY:',
        'LOCATION:Room: ',
        ' Yr',
    ], [
        '',
        '',
        '|',
        '&Period Start=',
        '&Fetch Time=',
        '&Period End=',
        '&UID=',
        '',
        '&Teacher=',
        '&Period=',
        '&Summary=',
        '&Room=',
        '&Year=',
    ], $str);
}

$events = explode('|', prep_vcard($txt));

$result = [];
foreach ($events as $key => $event) {
    parse_str(trim($event), $t);
    $result[] = array_map('trim', $t);
}

// remove empty elements
$result = array_filter($result);

// fix dates
array_walk($result, function(&$value, $key) {
    $value['Period_Start'] = date_create($value['Period_Start'])->format('d/m/Y h:i:s');
    $value['Fetch_Time']   = date_create($value['Fetch_Time'])->format('d/m/Y h:i:s');
    $value['Period_End']   = date_create($value['Period_End'])->format('d/m/Y h:i:s');
});

echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

https://3v4l.org/m4Ega

**Result:**

```
[
    {
        "Period_Start": "29\/01\/2018 10:03:00",
        "Fetch_Time": "04\/02\/2018 04:13:50",
        "Period_End": "29\/01\/2018 10:10:00",
        "UID": "beca07a3ddd48e6b725198ab61dbaaf149b4d5fd@sentral.local",
        "Teacher": "Mrs LOLITA BARLOW",
        "Period": "RC",
        "Summary": "10RC5: Roll Call",
        "Year": "10",
        "Room": "R302"
    },
    {
        "Period_Start": "29\/01\/2018 10:10:00",
        "Fetch_Time": "04\/02\/2018 04:13:50",
        "Period_End": "29\/01\/2018 11:10:00",
        "UID": "88dba308e8c588d0c7fa56183cbb5df9f2f1f046@sentral.local",
        "Teacher": "Miss PENELOPE WORLEY",
        "Period": "1",
        "Summary": "10MATH2N: Mathematics",
        "Year": "10",
        "Room": "B102"
    },
    {
        "Period_Start": "29\/01\/2018 11:10:00",
        "Fetch_Time": "04\/02\/2018 04:13:50",
        "Period_End": "30\/01\/2018 12:10:00",
        "UID": "bd3340d8f5a36cddd6f4016526fc6c06e38a526c@sentral.local",
        "Teacher": "Mrs Gaye SMITH",
        "Period": "2",
        "Summary": "10HSPZ: Hospitality",
        "Year": "10",
        "Room": "Y101"
    },
    {
        "Period_Start": "30\/01\/2018 12:50:00",
        "Fetch_Time": "04\/02\/2018 04:13:50",
        "Period_End": "30\/01\/2018 01:50:00",
        "UID": "d2a1dba62dc1b0ff1aa2e9d1ece25b1e9d5cfa12@sentral.local",
        "Teacher": "Mr Colin ARCHER",
        "Period": "3",
        "Summary": "10SCI4: Science",
        "Year": "10",
        "Room": "G201"
    }
]
```

Comment: Wow! That is heaps easier to understand! Thank you so much! I know this is probably too much to ask but is there a way we can convert the time stamps to the follow Date Time format? `d/m/Y h:i:s`

Comment: Thank you! It works really well, however I am getting undefined indexes for some odd reason 

<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: Period_Start in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Timetable/timetable.class.php</b> on line <b>97</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: Fetch_Time in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Timetable/timetable.class.php</b> on line <b>98</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: Period_End in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Timetable/timetable.class.php</b> on line <b>99</b><br />

Comment: Make sure `$result = array_filter($result);` is still there.

Comment: yes, it's still there: the full* code is: https://ghostbin.com/paste/k7ks4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164482/discussion-between-lawrence-cherone-and-joseph-shenton).

Answer (score 0):

I STILL NEED HELP HOWEVER!

I managed to fix this with a very simple fix which only just came to me.

Here is what I did to fix it:

```
<?php 

    $toFind = array("\n", "UID:", "Teacher: ", "BEGIN:VCALENDAR", "VERSION:2.0", "BEGIN:VEVENT", "DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:", "DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:", "DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:", "DESCRIPTION:", "\\nPeriod: ", "Period: RC", "SUMMARY:", "Yr", "LOCATION:Room: ", "PRODID:-//My Timetable//", "\r");

    $toReplace = array("", "\nUID: ", "\nTeacher: ", "", "", "", "\nPeriod End: ", "\nFetch Time: ", "Period Start: ", "", "\nPeriod: ", "Period: Role Call", "\nSummary: ", "\nYear: ", "\nRoom: ", "", "");

    $resp = str_replace($toFind, $toReplace, $resp);

    $array = array();
    $array = explode("END:VEVENT", $resp);

    foreach($array as $key => $str)
    {
        $array[$key] = explode("\n", $str);
    }

    $array2 = array();

    foreach ($array as $position => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $pos => $value) {
            $value = explode(": ", $value);
            $name = str_replace(" ", "_", strtolower($value[0]));
            $match = $value[1];
            $array2[$position]["$name"] = $match;
        }
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    return json_encode($array2, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

?>
```

However is gives this error yet it is fully working and shows the value of that key

**Notice**:  Undefined offset: 1 in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php** on line **121**

Comment: I'm gonna do you better than that.  Just need a little more time.

Comment: Your Notice comes because of `$array = explode("END:VEVENT", $resp);`  This generates an extra/unwanted empty element at the end of the array because you are asking for an explosion on the very last characters in the string.  You _could_ write `$array[$key]=array_filter($array[$key]);` immediately after the explode line, but it wouldn't be as fast as my first method.

Answer (score 0):

To convert all of the timestamps to your desired format, I'm calling `preg_replace_callback()` on the input string before the multi-dimensional array is generated.

Named capture groups do no allow spaces, key assignments have to be performed after capturing.

My pattern uses the `x` pattern modifier to ignore white-spaces in the pattern.  This allows the pattern to be written on multiple lines for improved readability.

The capture group patterns are specifically designed to avoid any unnecessary white-space trimming after capturing.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/df67b5a270531a768a2433b18d1ec729fe554bba))

```
$resp=preg_replace_callback('~DATE-TIME:\K\d{8}T\d{6}Z~',function($m){return date_create($m[0])->format('d/m/Y h:i:s');},$resp);

if(preg_match_all('~BEGIN:VEVENT\R+
                    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\R+
                    DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\R+
                    DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\R+
                    UID:(\S*)\R+
                    DESCRIPTION:Teacher:\s(.*)\\\nPeriod:\s(\S*)\R+
                    SUMMARY:(.*)\sYr(\S*)\R+
                    LOCATION:Room:\s(\S*)\R+
                    END:VEVENT\R*~x',
                    $resp,$out,PREG_SET_ORDER)){
    $keys=['Period Start','Fetch Time','Period End','UID','Teacher','Period','Summary','Room','Year'];
    echo json_encode(
            array_map(
                function($m)use($keys){
                    return array_combine($keys,array_slice($m,1));  // assign keys to captured values
                },
                $out
            ),
            JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
        );
}else{
    echo 'fail';
}
```

This outputs your desired structure.

---

This is a slower performing version, but perhaps easier to read:

```
$pattern='~BEGIN:VEVENT\R+
           DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:(\d{8}T\d{6}Z)\R+
           DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:(\d{8}T\d{6}Z)\R+
           DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:(\d{8}T\d{6}Z)\R+
           UID:(\S*)\R+
           DESCRIPTION:Teacher:\s(.*)\\\nPeriod:\s(\S*)\R+
           SUMMARY:(.*)\sYr(\S*)\R+
           LOCATION:Room:\s(\S*)\R+
           END:VEVENT\R*~x';

if(preg_match_all($pattern,$resp,$out,PREG_SET_ORDER)){
    foreach($out as $i=>$row){
        $prepared[$i]=[
            'Period Start'=>date_create($row[1])->format('d/m/Y h:i:s'),
            'Fetch Time'=>date_create($row[2])->format('d/m/Y h:i:s'),
            'Period End'=>date_create($row[3])->format('d/m/Y h:i:s'),
            'UID'=>$row[4],
            'Teacher'=>$row[5],
            'Period'=>$row[6],
            'Summary'=>$row[7],
            'Room'=>$row[8],
            'Year'=>$row[9]
            ];
    }
    echo json_encode($prepared,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}else{
    echo 'fail';
}
```

Comment: @JosephShenton Are your `Year` values only secondary school range?  Do you have primary school year values that are less than `1`?  Are they `P` for prep? or `K` ? or `0`? Do the `Period` values count up from `1`? These are important to answer to avoid hiccups later.

Comment: Performance comparisons: https://3v4l.org/811mv/perf#output versus https://3v4l.org/ZlFJL/perf#output versus https://3v4l.org/HW0tQ/perf#output